# I used the wrong billing name when I purchased a flight

Tags: air-travel, tickets, payment-cards

I bought a ticket using my boyfriend's credit card. However, due to lack of concentration, O accidentally put my name on the billing info instead of his. I received my confirmation email, but I'm curious as to know if this will be an issue when I go receive my boarding pass. Any advice please? My flight is tomorrow.

Comment: Which airline? Has the card been charged?

Answer (score 2):

When you have your ticket, you have it. There should be no issues.

If there would have been an issue, it would have happened at the moment of booking - the credit card payment would not have gone through, and your booking would not have completed. As it obviously got through, all is fine.

The airline has their money, so they couldn't care less anymore.